# How to securely parse SAML metadata?

Tags: xml, security, saml

I am working on a project that supports SSO SAML authorization/authentication. Last security analysis showed that we have security vulnerabilities related to XML External Entities Injection attacks. Here is the problematic part of code:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(metadata.getBytes());

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc;
doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
```

I searched in the Internet and found different solutions, some of them are working for general XML document parsing. Also I found solutions, that were disabling particular options of parser (such as expanding external entities). But I don't know if that solutions are acceptable for my case. So my question is: what is the most secure way of parsing SAML metadata?

Thanks,
Rafik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to rely on a well-known and third-party mantained software as ESAPI library of OWASP. This has become a de facto standard.
You could validate it with dedicated ESAPI tools and any known malicious input is filtered off. After this operation, you can parse it in your way.

[This is the link to ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=Home)